# How do you order descending using crossfilters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, crossfilter

I have a crossfilter object with date_value as the dimension.

```
$scope.x = cf.dimension(function (d) {return moment(d.date_value).format('L');});
```

I'm applying the following crossfilter functions to it.

```
$scope.y = $scope.x.group().reduce(add, remove, init);
```

I need to get the bottom 7 records from $scope.y, but I don't see that function as an option anymore. I can only do top(7). I was thinking I could do a descending order() then grab top(7). How would I do a descending order?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve only the last seven elements of array `$scope.x.group()`?

Comment: Yes, I need to apply reduce first though.

Comment: Crossfilter groups are usually sorted by their value, not their key, when calling `top`. So you could switch the order of the group if you always want the smallest groups first. Or you could do as suggested below and use `group.top(Infinity).slice(-7)`. Note that there is no option to order groups by key, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.slice()` following call to `.reduce()` with parameter `-7` to create a new array containing the last seven indexes of original array.

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
let lastSeven = arr.slice(-7);
console.log(lastSeven);
```